# Sessions work in Chrome but not IE

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, cookies

We had some issue internally using sessions and to solve this we had to comment out

> HTTPder set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure

in the httpd.conf.local file as we use https and not http. This solved the issue in chrome but IE still wont accept sessions.

Running the below script shows the sessions working in chrome but in IE the arrays are blank

```
session_start();

echo 'Cookies:<br>';
var_dump($_COOKIE);
echo '<br>';

echo 'Session:<br>';
var_dump($_SESSION);

$_SESSION['test-8165'] = 'test';
```

Cookies:
array(0) { } 
Session:
array(0) { }

Any ideas why this will work in chrome and not IE?

Comment: Are you serving your website over https?

Comment: you need to go through http://slacatalogue/sesh1.php to acced it but its over https i have been told

Comment: Not directly an answer, but: with setting `ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);`  you can force PHP to maintain the session-ID via the query-string.